# Significance of continuous rain background in "Dhootha" web series

Tags: plot-explanation, dhootha

In the [Dhootha](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt19868374/) web series, I noticed that the entire series is set against a backdrop of continuous rainfall. The opening scene features a weather prediction mentioning a storm in the Bay of Bengal as below

> Rainfall prediction in the Bay of Bengal. A storm is definitely on its way.
> This weather shall persist for the coming week. The Weather Board calls for precaution.

The rain starts when Chandra Murthy steps out of the auto to attend Sagar Varma's newspaper (Samachar) launching function, and it concludes when "Chandra Murthy" receives the editor offer from Jeevan Corp.

I'm curious about the artistic and narrative choices behind this constant rain background. Was it purely an aesthetic decision, or does it hold symbolic or thematic significance in the story-line?
Are there any specific moments or character developments tied to the rainy setting? I'm trying to understand if there's a deeper meaning or necessity for the persistent rain throughout the series.

Answer (score 0):

The movie poster show the character under an umbrella, and words (idea, events) fall like rain drops. I'm not sure if I must classify this as an [allegory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory) or a [metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor).

[image: Dhootha movie poster]

> In this supernatural thriller, journalist Sagar's life turns upside down when newspapers predict chilling incidents that unfold in his life. [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt19868374/)

> It refers to a journalist embedded in an organization, revealing incidents within a newsroom setting. Investigative journalism, in particular, involves a lot of risk. [Vikram K Kumar](https://industryhit.com/t/dhootha-is-technically-brilliant-shot-in-rain-for-100-days-chays-magic-vikram-k-kumar/)

> Being a journalist is a powerful role. In the democracy, journalism is a cornerstone. Investigative journalism, in particular, involves a lot of risk. To be in that profession, one needs a lot of guts. Not everyone can do that job. [Teluguone](https://www.teluguone.com/tmdb/amp/news/We-have-shot-Dhootha-for-100-days-in-the-rain-says-Vikram-K-Kumar-en-166158c1.html)

In order to do a (sometimes) dangerous job, an investigation journalist must have brain, guts, help, and maybe luck too. He needs to keep focused on his job/goal, no matter what happens (think of the image: "*falls on him*"), and needs to be protected. Your qualities and strenght protect you as much as possible, like an umbrella can do with rain. You have supernatural elements, and the darkness of the background helps setting/keeping the atmosphere chilling. The rain provides a dark pallet, dark background, for dark side and dark events. That's my interpretation, reinforced by following sources.

> **Every scene in Dhootha has a rain backdrop giving the narration even more depth**. [Dhootha: an interesting aspect about the shooting](https://www.123telugu.com/mnews/dhootha-an-interesting-aspect-about-the-shoot-is-here.html#google_vignette)

> Despite many visually impressive scenes in Dhootha, thanks to cinematographer Mikolaj Sygula, its colour grading is somewhat vexing as the overt and unnecessary use of a blue tint and sepia in a conventional manner seems to overemphasise what is already evident from the story and dialogues. **Although the recurring presence of rain adds charm to the series**, the frequent use of slow-motion raindrops as fillers has impacted the show’s rhythm. [Indian Express](https://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/web-series/dhootha-review-naga-chaitanya-parvathy-thiruvothus-thriller-series-is-marred-by-cliches-overreliance-on-the-supernatural-9049579/)

> **It’s set in a world which seems to be permanently drenched in rainfall because that’s how Fincher’s Se7en (1995) went about weaving its atmosphere**, but if one of the most noteworthy things in your show is a reference, that’s saying something. [Film Companion](https://www.filmcompanion.in/reviews/streaming-reviews/dhootha-review-a-sporadically-engaging-mystery-horror-series-that-squanders-its-potential-naga-chaitanya-vikram-k-kumar)

> As **the rain continues to pour, symbolizing both cleansing and turmoil**, Sagar’s journey reaches a cathartic conclusion. [Talkie's Corner](https://talkiescorner.com/dhootha-ending-explained/)

Many movies/scenes shot under heavy rain (for part or all of the movie) have also chilling (in every meaning of the word) background: [Identity (2003)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0309698/) -- [Seven Samurai (1954)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047478/) -- [Rush (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1979320/) -- [Partie de campagne (1936)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0028445/) -- [John Wick: Chapter 3 - Parabellum (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6146586/) -- [The Matrix Revolutions (2003)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242653/) -- [Point Break (1991)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102685/) -- [best movies featuring rain](https://culturedvultures.com/best-movies-featuring-rain/)

Comment: It's almost like tears in the rain. 'In this supernatural *noir* thriller'.... "Like many classic noirs, [Blade runner] is set in a version of Los Angeles where it constantly rains." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_noir - *noir* doesn't mean 'mystery' to me, it means *it's dark and it's raining*. Sin City, The Matrix, Road to Perdition, etc. - BTW, that's what will happen with climate change; only gets warmer and wetter from here on out.

Comment: @Mazura : agreed. I tried to convey that idea with "*The rain provides a dark pallet, dark background, for dark side and dark events.*"